# For multiple Booleans evaluation, is using && more efficient than ||?

Tags: c++

Assume we want to evaluate the Boolean value of `(A || B || C)`
which is logically equal to `!(!A && !B && !C)`.

Would it be more time-efficient to use `!(!A && !B && !C)` than the other if (!A) is false since the whole expression value becomes false? Will the program notice that? Or the program still needs to evaluate the value of (!B) and (!C) before returning the final result?

P.S. Just correcting the de'Morgan expressions and change from `~` to `!`. Thanks guys.

P.S.2 shown in [this link](https://godbolt.org/g/c5SsbG) by [Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920069/retired-ninja) and [optimized version](https://godbolt.org/g/8Hnoqb) by [David Foerster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2461638/david-foerster). The assembly code is actually the same!

Comment: Benchmark, benchmark, benchmark.  If you really want to know that is the best(only) way to really know.

Comment: [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Spoiler: these are not equivalent expressions.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer. Didn't really notice that the expressions weren't equivalent. I assumed the question was asked because they are, and didn't even bother check. :/

Comment: Would it be a shock if they generated the exact same assembly code? https://godbolt.org/g/c5SsbG

Comment: 1) Compilers are much smarter at optimizing code than you think. Much. Chances are, if two boolean expressions are equivalent, the compiler (in "Release" mode) will generate exactly the same code for both. 2) Don't worry about it. On any fairly recent machine, computation is virtually free. Execution speed depends on things like I/O latency, thread memory-contention, cache misses, etc... 3) Eschew early optimization.

Comment: Chained `||` is more efficient if you mostly expect/get `true`(s); `&&` is more efficient if you mostly expect/get `false`(s).  So it depends on your project.  As with all speed/efficiency questions you need to measure.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: [Enable optimization](https://godbolt.org/g/8Hnoqb) for better readability of the generate assembly code.

Answer (score 9):

`(A || B || C)` is logically equal to `!(!A && !B && !C)`, you were missing the inner `!`s. The short circuiting in the second expression happens when `!A` is `false`, or equivalently when `A` is `true`. But when `A` is `true`, the first expression also short-circuits. In other words, these two expressions behave the same way with respect to short circuiting.

As Retired Ninja mentions in a comment, the two expressions produce the same assembly code, so there is *no difference at all* between them, except that one is harder to read.